# Removing keycode in input

Tags: jquery

So, I have a following js code to show inputs:

```
  jQuery('#name').keyup(function(e){
                console.log(e);                    
                 if(e.which == 188) {
                    var tag  = jQuery(this).val();
                    var data = '<li>'+ name+'<a class="delete_name" title="'+ tag +'" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>Delete</b></a></li>';
                    tags.push(tag);
                    jQuery('.name ul').append(data);
                    jQuery(this).val('');
                }               
        });
```

For example, in this input, you can type names separated by comma.

However, I am getting the following result:

`steve,` `mike,` or `Ryan,`.

So, the comma becomes a part of the input.

Is there a way to "Not" recognize or remove "," in the input system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this line

```
jQuery('#name').keyup(function(e){
                console.log(e);                    
                 if(e.which == 188) {
                    var tag  = jQuery(this).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var data = '<li>'+ name+'<a class="delete_name" title="'+ tag +'" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>Delete</b></a></li>';
                    tags.push(tag);
                    jQuery('.name ul').append(data);
                    jQuery(this).val('');
                }               
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `keydown` or  `keypress` instead and capture the input before the value of the field is updated and then prevent the default behaviour if the key pressed is a comma:.

```
jQuery('#name').keypress(function(e){
            console.log(e);                    
             if(e.which == 188) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var tag  = jQuery(this).val();
                var data = '<li>'+ name+'<a class="delete_name" title="'+ tag +'" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>Delete</b></a></li>';
                tags.push(tag);
                jQuery('.name ul').append(data);
                jQuery(this).val('');
            }               
    });
```